# Simple wireless camera with API recommendations

Tags: camera, wireless, peripherals

I have a whiteboard and want to build a setup where I can press a button and have a picture of the whiteboard delivered to google drive.

I have a raspberry pi that acts as a little toy server for various other small projects and would like a wireless camera with a stupidly simple interface that I can hit from the raspberry pi.

Ideally I’d want a cheap, HD camera that doesn’t require interfacing with a cloud provider/have any apps/do any motion detection/etc, and is just a dumb wireless camera that can be assigned an ip address and returns a photo when hit with an api call.

Closest thing I’ve found are cameras people have made with raspberry pi zeros and camera modules, but I’d prefer not to build that part and use a really simple off the shelf camera.

Any advice on what camera to use, or know of electronic hobby catalogs that might have something like what I’m looking for?

EDIT: to clairfy, I’m looking for advice about raspberry pi specific or more generic peripherals, not necessarily particular purchase recommendations. I don’t know how to look for the kind of device I’m describing and would appreciate advice on how to find one, and am guessing other pi users have looked for similar devices/might know how to find one.

Comment: So you want purchase recommendations for a device that does not really involve a Pi. That looks off-topic to me https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Dirk There are a lot of people out there like me who use raspberry pi’s for projects like this, so I think there are other raspberry pi users who will find this question useful, and this seemed like the most appropriate forum for this question. If you have another suggestion I’m all ears.

Comment: @Dirk Specifically w/r/t the guidelines, this question is about raspberry pi peripherals, which is listed as on topic

Comment: checkout the esp32-cam boards. They are cheap and have an open API.